# HTML-- Faking the size of the browser window (to be smaller or larger)

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm attempting to make a page that will be compatible both with a PC browser and a browser on a phone.

Essentially, I want to size my elements as large as I can on the smaller screens (ideally, even a little bit larger), while confining everything to a narrow vertical band in the center on a PC browser window.

You can see the look I'm trying for here:
http://www.hoggy.com

I've attempted to read the browser's width to tweak the data on the fly, but I find I cannot get a reliable width on all platforms.

So I've attempted to center things, and make the image and table sizes be a percentage of the page size... but on a phone it's too small (thus I would like it to be actually a little wider than the phone screen) whereas on the PC, I want my width to be, effectively, min(100%,500px).

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Considered using a responsive framework like bootstrap?

Comment: Maybe look into viewport units (`vh` and `vw`, e.g. `100vw` is the whole viewport-width). https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Comment: Have you looked into media queries in CSS? They're very simple, reliable, etc. This is how you'd achieve a responsive web page without relying on some framework.

Comment: Do some research on media queries and viewports.  You basically have 1 set of CSS for a regular browser experience and then other CSS for different sizes and orientations.  Making 1 that fits all is more trouble than it's worth and honestly not worth pursuing.

Comment: Archer: It was research on media queries and viewports that led me to the discovery that a mobile browser would not reliably give the correct resolution information.  Also, my layout is very simple.  It most definitely is not more trouble than it's worth to center a column on a screen.  It's all going to just be a matter of syntax.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Simplest answer:

```css
html
{
max-width: 1024px

}
```